# Unable to load the Rcpp Package in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, r, git, rcpp

I have been trying to load the most recent version of the Rcpp package (GIT version XXXX) on a Windows Server 2008 R2 platform.  When I do so I get the following error:

```
> library(Rcpp)
Error : .onLoad failed in load Namespace() for 'Rcpp', details:
  call: new_dummyObject(.dummyInstancePointer)
  error: object 'class__dummyInstance' not found
In addition: Warning message:
package 'Rcpp' was built under R version 3.0.3
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcpp'
```

I have discussed this with one of the package authors on [GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/147) and we have determined that it is most likely a local issue.  (That being said after more careful investigation, the problem in that post is not exactly the same as what I am getting) I am able to load the same package using Windows Server 2003 using R version 3.0.1 and 3.0.3.  I am coping portions of the linked post here for convenience.  The procedure that I followed to generate the package was the following:

1. Downloaded the most recent master code from Github (Should be commit 5b510ed)
2. Uncompressed the zip file in a temporary directory and rename 'Rcpp-master' to 'Rcpp'
3. Installed Rtools version 3.1
4. Ensured that RTools bin and the related gcc bin directory was at the beginning of my path
5. Used the command "R CMD BUILD Rcpp" to generate the Rcpp_0.11.1.2.tar.gz file
6. Use the command "R CMD INSTALL --build --compile-both Rcpp_0.11.1.2.tar.gz to generate the Rcpp_0.11.1.2.zip
7. Copy the resulting zip archive to the Windows Server 2008 machine
8. Used the R native install local package to install the Rcpp package

Based on the package authors suggestion, I looked at the .libPaths() output on both the working and the not working R versions.  In both cases the output was exactly the same:

```
[1] "\\\\vnxserver/home/MYACCT/My Documents/R/win-library/3.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library"
```

I am really at a loss for what to try next in the debugging chain and I am hopeful that some of the SO community can point me in the right direction.  (That is why I am kind of reposting here).  Any comments are welcome.

Though I posted it in the paragraph earlier, it might not be clear that the related discussion on GitHub is at https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/147

Comment: The other things that would be useful to confirm: what version is the R 'native install'? Are you sure you're installing in the library denoted in the output of `.libPaths()`? Where does `R` actually point to on that system? What version is it? What library does `R CMD INSTALL` say it's installing in?

Comment: You have asked many good follow-up questions.  I have verified that the library is in-fact being installed in the first .libPaths() output location.  After some further work, I think that I may have uncovered the problem.  The system is currently setup so that I can not execute binary applications from my home directory (and all dirs below).  I believe that Windows is not allowing the dll file to be properly loaded which is causing the problem.  I will be investigating this on Monday hopefully and will have an answer.  If this is the problem, then R should have gave me a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working to properly debug the problem, the issue was with Windows in the long run.  Our security administraitors had setup the permissions of the system such that dll files could not be loaded from specific directories.  After working with our IT staff I was able to get R packages that use dll files placed in a special location and then simply add that special location onto the library search path by using the `.libPaths()` function.  To make is easier for the end users I placed the appropriate code in the system wide `RProfile.site` file to handle this extra library search directory issue.

Problem solved...

As an aside, I think that R should have notified that there were some strangeness going on when it tried to open a library and did not have any associated symbols...  At least a warning...

I have edited this answer to have the relevant snipplet from my `Rprofile.site` file to add directories to the library search path.  The file was placed in `c:/program files/R/R-3.0.2/etc`.

```
.First = function() {
  cat('Adding LocalLibrary to the Library Search Path ... ')
  .libPaths(c(.libPaths(), <your library path you want to add>))

  if(<your path you want to add> %in% .libPaths()) {
    cat('Success\n')
  } else {
    cat('Failure\n')
    cat('You may encounter problems using libraries that depend on dynamically loaded dll files\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. Can you share the Rprofile.site code solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show the code that was used.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @JustaceClutter I know you've made this most a long time ago, but I'm having very similar issues. The error I get is exectly the same. R is installed on my windows 7 Machine. This is a work computer so we might be running Windows Server. But I'm certain R is installed on the C drive.
Are you able to explain what folder setting you used,I showed our IT team your post but the have not idea how to address this.

Comment: I don't window..  Sorry.  I was just going by what our IT team had said.  They have the system locked down so that dll's and exe's can not be loaded/executed from our user directories.

Comment: After seveal months of trying I finally got it working. As @JustaceClutter said, it was IT security issue. I sat down with IT and they used thier security s/w to see which files are being blocked by their firewall when I run packages. 
Effectively, it was all `.dll` file that got blocked. They figured out a set of rules that allowed me to run R packages from a seperate folder on my hard drive without giving me Admin rights to that folder.
But all you really need is a folder with Admin rights.

Comment: Great news that you figured it out.